# how thread support works in the operating system High Sierra?

Tags: multithreading, macos, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

I can not find any content that addresses this research. I've already looked at Apple's own website and still found nothing.
Has anyone here read about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is a little broad. Perhaps you can narrow it down a bit or describe what research you did. In answer to your question, we generally don’t use threads directly, but rather use “dispatch queues” (part of “grand central dispatch”), which abstracts us away from the weeds of managing threads.

Comment: If you _really_ have to do your own threading, see [The Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html). That has largely been superseded by Grand Central Dispatch as discussed in the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091), notably the section titled “moving away from threads”.

Comment: thank you, i'll read it later